# Transferring nested JSONs to new line in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a JSON file in an S3 Bucket that I need to transform to a JSON where the array it contains has been split so one array element is in each line. This is what my file basically looks like:

```
{"variable":"VALUE", "variable1":"VALUE1", "variable2":"VALUE2", "arrayvariable":[{"nestedelement":"VALUEa","nestedelement1":"VALUEb","unixtimestamp":bigint}]}
{"variable":"VALUE3", "variable1":"VALUE4", "variable2":"VALUE5", "arrayvariable":[{"nestedelement":"VALUEc","nestedelement1":"VALUEd","unixtimestamp":bigint1},{"nestedelement":"VALUEe","nestedelement1":"VALUEf","unixtimestamp":bigint2}]}
...
```

As you can see, a list of JSON objects, each separated by a linebreak, the last element of the object is an array of one or more structs. 
The schema I get when I crawl this file into AWS Glue is the following:

```
variable string
variable1 string
variable2 string
arrayvariable array<struct<nestedelement:string,nestedelement1:string,unixtimestamp:bigint>>
```

This seems sensible.

What I then need is a table that contains the following:

```
variable variable1 arrayvariable.nestedelement arrayvariable.nestedelement1 arrayvariable.unixtimestamp

VALUE VALUE1 VALUEa VALUEb bigint
VALUE3 VALUE4 VALUEc VALUEb bigint1
VALUE3 VALUE4 VALUEe VALUEf bigint2
```

This is a table that contains the first variable values as they come, but duplicates them for every element of the array, just changing the second edition to match the second array elements and so forth. I know it would be preferable to use a second table to contain the array contents with a foreign key for the data set it belongs to. However, that is not the use-case we have.

What I get at the moment is the following table:

```
variable variable1 arrayvariable unixtimestamp

VALUE VALUE1 "[{""nestedelement"": ""VALUEa""
VALUE3 VALUE4 "[{""nestedelement"": ""VALUEa""
```

So part of the array is missing, but the column with the array always contains [{. There is a separate column for the unixtimestamp, however it is empty. Mysteriously in some data sets the field for arrayvariable also is empty.

I have tried many things to fix this. One edit caused the arrayvariable column to just contain the entire array, but missing in some lines. Some edits wrote JSON files to my S3 bucket that also contained the array as above, but Athena would not have it.

The second part of what I need is the reason, I am currently writing the results of my transformation into an S3 Bucket: I need the whole thing to be accessible from QuickSight in the end. As far as I know there is a way of making that work with Athena, but I haven't gotten into that a lot yet, because the base is still missing.

How can I solve this problem?